# cocos2d Display an array of strings in 3 columns in objective-c on iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios4, text

Basically, I know that Label works for the basic string. But what I want to do firstly is to display the contents of the array in 3 columns of 8-9 rows each. How do I do so?

`answersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"levers", @"revels", @"elver", @"elves", @"leers", @"lever", @"reels", @"revel", @"serve", @"sever", @"veers", @"verse", @"eels", @"else", @"ever", @"eves", @"leer", @"lees", @"reel", @"seer", @"veer", @"eel", @"ere", @"eve", @"lee", @"see", nil];`

Aside from that, I will be symbolically putting "blank" images for each letter, so it would look something like this on the screen of the device:

`

```
■■■   ■■■■   ■■■■■
eel   ■■■■   ■■■■■■
■■■   ■■■■
see   ■■■■
■■■   ■■■■
■■■■  ■■■■■
■■■■  ■■■■■
ever
```

`

the ■ symbolize the png file I will be using. The app sort of replaces the squares with the correct word later on.

Anyway, how do I go about doing this? I am using objective-c and the iphone sdk.

Thank you, and I hope someone can help me out with this.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom formatted text, especially if it includes images, I strongly recommend using `UIWebView` and laying out the text/images in a basic html file. The other option is to hard code things into a `UIScrollView`, with `UILabel`s and `UIImageView`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a UITableView.  For each row in the table view, use a custom UITableViewCell that has 3 labels in it.